# Spring XML equivalent of @EnableEntityLinks

Tags: spring, spring-hateoas

What is XML equivalent of [@EnableEntityLinks](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-hateoas/blob/master/readme.md#entitylinks) annotation in Spring?

I've been searching for some time, so my guess would be it does not exist yet, but I have to check.